# Which of the following sentences is correct

Tags: conjunctions

Which of the  following  sentences is correct:

> Please do let me know prior filing so immediately rectification could be done.

OR

> Please do let me know so immediately rectification could be done prior filing the documents.

Comment: You should provide more context. Neither sentence is even _close_ to being "correct" grammatical English. Please use the **[edit]** link to tell us what usage you would like to know about. If you don't do this, your question may unfortunately be closed, and we would rather provide you with an answer.

Comment: @P.E.Dant It would certainly be useful for the OP to ask a more specific question. I'm reminded of the ubiquitous IT questions where someone throws up some code and asks "why doesn't it work?"

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence is correct; they both have similar mistakes. First, *prior filing* should be *prior to filing* in both. Next, *could* should be *can*. Finally, *immediately* is a "misplaced modifier," meaning you have it in the wrong place. In general, the modifier should be placed next to the word it modifies. We don't really know where you want to apply the word immediately.

Let's look at some possible corrections to your first sentence:

> Please do let me know immediately prior to filing so rectification can be done.
>   Please do let me know immediately, so rectification can be done prior to filing.
>   Please do let me know prior to filing, so rectification can be immediately done/done immediately.

In the last sentence, the words *done* and *immediately* can be transposed without changing the meaning.

In the first sentence, the meaning of *immediately prior* is *just before*. So it means please wait until the last minute before filing before you let me know. The second sentence means to let me know right away, so that I can get the rectification done before the filing deadline. The last one means to let me know sometime before filing, so I can drop what I'm doing and get the rectification done right away.

I'm going to say that the second sentence makes the most sense. Your second sentence is closest to that meaning. If corrected, it would read like this:

> Please do let me know immediately, so rectification can be done prior to filing the documents.

Comment: BobRodes . Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. I really appreciate it

Comment: @KareemMusa You are very welcome.